# Finding the image source when clicking a button created with :before pseudo class

Tags: jquery

I am making a Pinterest button, by adding a pseudo class `:before` to all images, appending the button to all images with JQuery, like this:

```
(function appendPinterestIcon() {

    $('img').before('<span class="pinterest"></span>');

}());
```

Then later, when the user clicks on the dynamically created button, I want to get the `src`, using JQuery again:

```
var shareImage = $(this).closest('img').attr('src');
```

This, however, doesn't grab the source of the image. Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: You're maybe inserting content before a given element, but what you're *definitely* not doing is using the `::before` pseudo-element; since it's almost entirely inaccessible to JavaScript at the moment.

Comment: FYI `before()` in jQuery does not create a `:before` pseudo element - it inserts the content before that in the selector. Pseudo elements are out of the reach of javascript as they are not part of the DOM. Also, how have you attached the code in your second block to the `span`? Seeing the full code would help here.

Comment: Ok, I have added this to a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5erux6y2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.closest()` looks at the element itself, and if it isn't what you're looking for, it traverses up the DOM tree, looking at **parents**, siblings are ignored.

If you are inserting the button right before each image (using `.before()`), then the button becomes a **sibling**, not a parent, to that image.  You want to use `.next()` when a button is clicked to find the image that comes right after it.

```
var shareImage = $(this).next('img').attr('src');
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6n456wac/)

Comment: Yes, I had a nested button in my code. Came up with a similar solution: var shareImage = $(this).parent().next().attr('src');